# Python convert xml to csv with BeautifulSoup doesn't work on azure

Tags: python, xml, csv, beautifulsoup

I have an issue converting xml to csv file using BeautifulSoup in azure App Service. when I run it locally everything is fine. the first difference is at the soup line:

Parsing code:

```
file_path = os.path.join(INPUT_DIRECTOR, "test.xml")
source = open(file_path, encoding="utf8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.read(), 'xml')    #doesn't work on global server
First = [case.text for case in soup.find_all('FirstAtt')]
Second = [case.text for case in soup.find_all('SecondAtt')]
Third= [case.text for case in soup.find_all('ThirdAtt')]
results = list(zip(First, Second))
columns = ['1', '2']
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=columns)
df['ID'] = Third[0]
df.to_csv(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <ThirdAtt>7290027600007</ThirdAtt>
  <Items Count="279">
    <Item>
      <FirstAtt>2021-09-05 08:00</FirstAtt>
      <SecondAtt>5411188134985</SecondAtt>
      ...
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <FirstAtt>2021-09-05 08:00</FirstAtt>
      <SecondAtt>5411188135005</SecondAtt>
      ...
    </Item>
    ...
```

On local ip run the soup line is able to read the xml file, but on global server run on azure soup isn't reading the file and remaind as :

```
soup = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to @balderman, I have converted my soup use as recommended:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
headers = []
for idx,item in enumerate(root.findall('.//Item')):
    data = []
    if idx == 0:
        headers = [x.tag for x in list(item)]
    for h in headers:
        data.append(item.find(h).text)

    First.append(data[0])
    Second.append(data[1])
    results = list(zip(First, Second))
    ...
```

Is there a way to use generic indexes for the appends incase the place in data[i] will change?

Comment: If its azure, why its tagged as aws?

Comment: You're right, @balderman removed the tag.

Comment: What does ```soup.read()``` give you on azure ? Does it print the contents correctly ?

Comment: It doesn't, it remains soup = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and then all the soup.find_all are empty.

Comment: "Is there a way to use generic indexes for the appends incase the place in data[i] will change?" - not sure I understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for ANY external lib - just use core python ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<root>
  <ThirdAtt>7290027600007</ThirdAtt>
  <Items Count="279">
    <Item>
      <FirstAtt>2021-09-05 08:00</FirstAtt>
      <SecondAtt>5411188134985</SecondAtt>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <FirstAtt>2021-09-05 08:00</FirstAtt>
      <SecondAtt>5411188135005</SecondAtt>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</root>
'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
headers = []
for idx,item in enumerate(root.findall('.//Item')):
    data = []
    if idx == 0:
        headers = [x.tag for x in list(item)]
        print(','.join(headers))
    for h in headers:
        data.append(item.find(h).text)
    print(','.join(data))
```

output

```
FirstAtt,SecondAtt
2021-09-05 08:00,5411188134985
2021-09-05 08:00,5411188135005
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works on azure for me. I have updated my post with your implementation, and have a small question there.